# Build view outside of an anctivity android studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an app in Java.
I have a class named Affichage whitch extend of MainActivity.

I would like to generate a ConstraintLayout (and more) and display it on MainActivity.

Here the code in Affichage Class:

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = new ConstraintLayout(super.getBaseContext());
```

and I have this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Context.isUiContext()' on a null object reference
```

When I trying:

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = new ConstraintLayout(this);
```

in MainActivity, it's work so I think it is an issue of context.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

An `Activity` *is* a `Context` (it's a subclass of `Context`) so that's why you can just pass `this` as the `context` parameter inside `MainActivity`.

If `Affichage` *extends* `MainActivity`, then it's a `Context` too, and you should be able to pass `this` there as well.

---

Your problem isn't access to the context, your issue is that when you *do* access it, it's *null*:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Context.isUiContext()' on a null object reference
```

That means that something's got a `Context` reference, and it's trying to call `isUiContext` on it, but the object is actually null. You're not calling that, so it's probably happening inside the `ConstraintLayout` constructor.

---

Basically you're calling it right, the problem is the `Activity` doesn't *have* a context yet, so when `getContext()` is called, it returns null.

This usually happens when you try to initialise something in an `Activity` before `onCreate` is called, which is when the context has been set on the activity. If you call `new ConstraintLayout(this)` in `onCreate`, it will work.

If you do it in the top level (like `private ConstraintLayout layout = new ConstraintLayout(this)`) then that will happen at construction time, before you have a context, and it'll fail. So if you ever need to access the context, you have to make sure you do it *inside* `onCreate` or *after* `onCreate` has run.